# Resuming log shipping, do I just restore the db over itself?

Tags: sql-server-2012, log-shipping

I have log shipping set up.

I then bring all the databases online on the secondary machine, so log shipping can't restore anymore.

A bit later on I want to resume log shipping.

I was told before that to do this I should do a full copy of the database back from primary, overwrite it and put it into no recovery mode. This works.

I am wondering if this is necessary though - doesn't it ship the entire log? If I restored a blank database, wouldn't it just run the restore from primary job and we're back in business?

I basically I have 20 databases to put back into no recovery mode after I bring the secondary server online when I am done with it, and manually backing up and copying them all from live and restoring would be a tough job, so I am trying to automate it.

I should add that I'm not interested in preserving any data on the secondary machine. It's basically an emergency machine that keeps some services running if the primary one fails, it doesn't store anything important.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes if you've brought the database into read-write mode at any point, you can't just resume log shipping - you essentially need to start over. If you are using it for read only operations that's a bit different, because you can restore logs with standby, and have the database usable (you just can't *write* to it).